# How to get a value of <#= Id #> when passed to a helper method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am using `ASP.NET MVC 3` with `razor`.  I am also using the latest version of `Telerik MVC`.

I have a grid on my view displaying a list of applications.  Each application has a state.  I need to write a helper method to display links in each row of the grid depending on each application's current state.  If the state is 1 then I need to display an Edit link.  The helper that I have looks like this:

```
public static string ActionLinks(this HtmlHelper helper, string grantApplicationId, string grantApplicationStateId)
{
     List<TagBuilder> linkList = new List<TagBuilder>();
     string actionLinks = string.Empty;

     if (grantApplicationStateId == "1")
     {
          // Edit link
          TagBuilder editLink = new TagBuilder("a");
          editLink.MergeAttribute("href", "/GrantApplication/Edit/" + grantApplicationId);
          editLink.InnerHtml = "Edit";
          linkList.Add(editLink);
     }

     foreach (TagBuilder link in linkList)
     {
          actionLinks += link.ToString() + "<br>";
     }

     return actionLinks;
}
```

The grid column in my Telerik grid looks like this:

```
column.Bound(x => x.Id)
     .ClientTemplate(@Html.ActionLinks("<#= Id #>", "<#= GrantApplicationStateType.Id #>"))
     .Title("Actions");
```

My view model looks like:

```
public class GrantApplicationListViewModel
{
     // Just partial properties
     public GrantApplicationStateType GrantApplicationStateType { get; set; }
}
```

And GrantApplicationStateType looks like:

```
public class GrantApplicationStateType : IEntity
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When the above helper method is called then the value of grantApplicationStateId is "<#= GrantApplicationStateType.Id #>".  How would I get the value that was passed through?  What I mean is, if the value is 1 that was passed through, how would I get 1 because currently it is "<#= GrantApplicationStateType.Id #>"?

**UPDATE 2012-02-06**

I tried Darin's link, used the exact same sample in my code, but changed the following:

```
column.ActionLink("Open", "Edit", "GrantApplication", item => new { id = item.Id, applicationStateId = item.GrantApplicationStateType.Id });
```

I need to pass through 2 values.  I need to do a couple of if statements on the grant application state id, and then return the specific action links to the client.  But it fails when looping through the values in:

```
if (memberExpression.Expression is ParameterExpression)
     value = string.Format("<#= {0} #>", memberExpression.Member.Name);
else
     value = GetValue(memberExpression);
```

The first parameter passed in goes through the first/true part of the if statement:

```
value = string.Format("<#= {0} #>", memberExpression.Member.Name);
```

..but the second parameter goes through the false part of the if:

```
value = GetValue(memberExpression);
```

What's the difference between the 2?

And then it fails at the GetValue method with the following message:

```
variable 'item' of type MyProject.ViewModels.GrantApplicationListViewModel' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined
```

I can't get this to work, and I looked for some more samples and couldn't find any.

Comment: how does your model look like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this using a helper. In ASP.NET MVC helpers run on the server. Notice the `ClientTemplate` name in the Telerik grid? That is meant to run on the client.

What it does is that it simply uses `<#= Id #>` as a placeholder to a server side helper which will generate some HTML and **on the client side**, the Telerik grid will do a simple string replace in order to put the value which is only known on the client.

At the moment your server side `ActionLinks` helper is invoked, the Telerik grid cannot pass you the actual value which is known only on the client.

You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://gedgei.wordpress.com/2011/07/02/telerik-mvc-grid-actionlink-column/) for a nice extension.

Comment: It seems like it will work, I will just have to modify it to fit in with my scenario.